# Mouse vertical scrolling speed issue in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have a laptop attached to a docking station that has a wireless mouse attached.  I have gone into the Mouse Properties and set the vertical scrolling speed to 3.  When I undock and use it, and then dock it back up again the vertical scrolling speed is obviously faster.  I go back to the properties and it still says 3.  I move it to 2 and back to 3 and click apply and it's back to normal.

What's going on?  I'm guessing it has to do with something resetting when docking/undocking, but I don't know how to fix it.  Does anybody know how to take care of this annoying problem?

Comment: Is there an updated driver you can download for the mouse from the manufacturer?

Comment: I have the latest version

Comment: When you undock it, is the mouse scroll speed setting changed?

Comment: Nope.  It's the same.

Comment: Do you use "Undock Computer" (or "Eject PC") for undocking?

Comment: I usually just shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS has since released a driver update via Windows Updates and it has fixed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> There are different profiles for a
>   laptop being docked and not docked.
>   I've seen these (on Dell laptops, at
>   least) get corrupted and doing odd
>   things to system settings (usually
>   network-related). If you right-click
>   on My Computer and choose Properties,
>   on one of the tabs, there is a
>   'Hardware Profiles' button. If you
>   delete the offending profile, the
>   system will re-create it next time it
>   is made active. That should solve the
>   issue. - [Creepygeek](https://superuser.com/users/8976/creepygeek)

I found a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/2693/mouse-wheel-scroll-setting-spontaneously-changes), and what I have quoted above seems like it would be helpful advice.

Comment: Hmmm, appears this applies to XP, but the feature was removed from Vista upwards.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling any "acceleration" settings from your Mouse driver