# Windows 7 scroll wheel settings are lost after resume from sleep

Tags: windows-7, windows, mouse, bluetooth

After my Windows 7 resumes from sleep, the mouse scroll wheel settings that specify the number of lines are always set to 1.  I have this set to 5, but it changes to 1 after every resume from sleep.

Any thoughts as to what might be resetting this to 1 each resume from sleep?

I am using Windows 7 64 bit with a bluetooth mouse.  I have the latest drivers installed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using hibernate instead of sleep and see if your settings will remain using that shut down method? http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Sleep-and-hibernation-frequently-asked-questions