# Vertical Scrolling with mouse wheel - number of lines at a time reverts to 1

Tags: windows-7, mouse-wheel

I would like this setting to stay at 3, but it keeps reverting to 1. In the middle of work, not after a reboot or anything like that. I notice it when web pages / documents scroll vertically slower than I'd like.

I did have to install a driver for this new mouse (MS Wireless Mobile Mouse 3500) which added the tab `Mouse and Keyboard Center`, but the behavior described existed before that installation.

This happens on the order of .. 5 times a day? Any ideas how to fix permanently?

lenovo e530 running win7.

[image]

Comment: I've been seeing this issue as well. I have a lenovo T420, also on win7. I move it between docks and use it with synergy. I don't see it as frequently as 5 times a day, usually a few times a week (both with microsoft and lenovo mice in docks, and microsoft mouse over synergy).

Comment: Where'd you get the driver for the mouse? Did Windows find it for you? Did it come from a CD? A website? Is it the most recent version? What driver is it? What happens without the driver?

Comment: So the laptop I have is a corporate image, I'm unsure about the thinkpad mouse drivers, but the others were installed by windows when plugging in the various mice.

Comment: Does the option in your screenshot literally revert back to "1", or does it remain at "3" while the effect changes anyways?

Comment: The number in the screenshot above changes to 1 for me when this problem occurs. Seems less often now, once every couple of days.

Comment: Me too on a ThinkPad W550s. My trackpad is disabled, scrolling is enabled on my trackpoint but I use that sometimes and don't want to turn it off. Wonder if I can run a script periodically that sets the value in the registry? If there even is a registry key for it.

Comment: Similar question: https://superuser.com/q/2693/6581

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ThinkPad also has a touchpad using a Synaptics driver.  That driver interferes with your Microsoft mouse.  This is a [known issue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222825), and Microsoft's solution is disable scrolling on the touchpad.

Comment: That is a pretty old KB (from 2001) and I'm on version 16.1.1.0 of the synaptics driver (the KB references version 5.0.17). Still, I'll test this, it may still be applicable, but I would hope after a decade and multiple operating systems later, this would have been addressed - but you never know. I should note that I'm also not using an intellipoint mouse - intellipoint was discontinued back in 2011.

Comment: Current mouse driver from when it happened today was mouclass.sys and mouhid.sys, file version 6.1.7600.16385 (HID-compliant mouse).

Comment: @MaQleod I'm willing to bet Synaptics considers this a feature and not a bug.

Comment: I've been testing for 2 days now, looks like disabling 1 finger scrolling for my trackpad was the answer. (2 finger scrolling is still enabled) Thanks!